# According to c standard j=i++ * i++ is undefined but j=i++ & i++ is legal why?

Tags: c, post-increment

According to standard c why it `j= i++ * i++` undefined and `j=i++ & i++` perfectly legal statement?

Comment: Both are undefined. Did you mean, `j=i++ && i++ `?

Comment: *According to the Standard* could you please provide chapter and verse?

Comment: Actually my friend got this question from some coaching institute but I found something confusing in it so posted.

Answer (score 4):

They are both undefined behavior.

```
j = i++ * i++; // undefined behavior
j = i++ & i++; // undefined behavior
```

The value of object `i` is modified more than once  between two sequence points in the two examples.

Answer (score 1):

```
j= i++ * i++ ;

j=i++ & i++ ;
```

Both are undefined because changing the i value between sequence points

Read [Why are these constructs undefined behavior?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949433/why-are-these-constructs-undefined-behavior)

Comment: Your link is tagged *C++* many of the concepts are different since *C++* now has *sequenced before and after* a good *C* question would be [Why are these constructs undefined behavior?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/949433/why-are-these-constructs-undefined-behavior).

Answer (score 1):

As the Mystical and ouah already said, both are undefined.

```
j = i++ && i++;
```

would be well-defined, since && short-cuts, which means, it must evalutate the left operand first, and then - if the left operand was true - the right operand.

Comment: `i++ && i++` is defined not because of short-cut but because `&&` operator introduces a sequence point after the evaluation of the first operand.

Comment: Can shortcut, or *must* shortcut? :)

Comment: @ouah: True, and it must do so, because it short-cuts.